# Extending Identify widget and connect it with Legend widget

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, identify

I am using latest Flex Identify widget and I have created my own legend widget.

What I am trying to do is, when a user select a point using Identify tool it selects some feature on the map. That feature refers to some common value in our legend. What I want is to highlight that value in legend widget.

For further explanation:

If within a feature we have 6 attributes coming from our layer and we have the same 6 features present in Legend widget, I want to connect/enhance the Identify widget so on point-click I can see the widget on the map as well as its properties on the Legend Widget.